# How to create a table with a BLOB datatype column in informix?

Tags: informix

I am going to create a table in a informix database whcih is with a BLOB data typed column.It is going to save a image data. Here is my syntax as follows.

```
create table blob_test_db
  (
    col1 varchar(10),
    img_bin BLOB in blob_dbspace
  ) extent size 32 next size 32 lock mode page;
```

According to my above syntax I want to store my `img_bin` data in `blob_dbspace` dbspace. I want to know is it possible? However above syntax is wrong. Please tell me the correct syntax for adding blob type column to the informix table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informix is tricky — it has two distinct families of 'large objects':

- `BYTE` and `TEXT` — classic blobs
- `BLOB` and `CLOB` — smart blobs

It can store BYTE or TEXT blobs `IN TABLE` or in a blob space (as opposed to a smart blob space or `sbspace`).  Except that you wrote BLOB instead of BYTE, the notation you used is correct for BYTE or TEXT blobs.

The notation for BLOB or CLOB blobs is different.  You're allowed to list multiple sbspaces for a BLOB or CLOB column:

```
CREATE TABLE blob_test_db
(
    col1    VARCHAR(10),
    img_bin BLOB
) PUT img_bin IN blob_dbspace EXTENT SIZE 32 NEXT SIZE 32 LOCK MODE PAGE;
```

See the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0509.htm) statement generally, and the [PUT clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0107.htm#ids_sqs_0107) in particular.